# Mapping a JSON object stored in Redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to map an object so that values will be accessible in my JSX each place it says `value`. The object is stored as const `{weather} = this.props`. Here is the JSX:

```
render() {
const { weather } = this.props;

return (
  <div className='card border-secondary mb-3'>
    <div className='card-header text-white bg-secondary'>City Information</div>
    <div className='card-body'>
    Lat/Long:
    <div className="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <div className='row'>
    <div className='col-md-4 text-center'>
    <h5>Tempurature (F)</h5>
    <h6 className ='text-info'>value</h6>
    </div>
    <div className='col-md-4 text-center'>
    <h5>Low (F)</h5>
    <h6 className ='text-info'>value</h6>
    </div>
    <div className='col-md-4 text-center'>
    <h5>High (F)</h5>
    <h6 className ='text-info'>value</h6>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div className='row'>
    <div className='col-md-4 text-center'>
    <h5>Pressure</h5>
    <h6 className ='text-info'>value</h6>
    </div>
    <div className='col-md-4 text-center'>
    <h5>Humidity</h5>
    <h6 className ='text-info'>value</h6>
    </div>
    <div className='col-md-4 text-center'>
    <h5>Wind Speed</h5>
    <h6 className ='text-info'>value</h6>
    <h5>Lat</h5>
    <h6 className ='text-info'>value</h6>
    </div>
    <h5>Long</h5>
    <h6 className ='text-info'>value</h6>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

My object looks like this:

```
{"coord":{"lon":-95.37,"lat":29.76},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":285.56,"pressure":1022,"humidity":67,"temp_min":283.05,"temp_max":287.15},"visibility":16093,"wind":{"speed":2.27,"deg":115.002},"clouds":{"all":1},"dt":1542935700,"sys":{"type":1,"id":2646,"message":0.0041,"country":"US","sunrise":1542977570,"sunset":1543015369},"id":4699066,"name":"Houston","cod":200}
```

How can I use `.map` method on my object to render the values that I want to display? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To map an object's properties instead of the usual array, you'll instead want to use the `Object.keys(this.props.weather).map(...)` function. This will give you the key names of the weather object (ie: coord, wind). You can then use that name to get the weather object's property like so: `this.props.weather[weatherPropertyKey].speed` for the 'wind' key, for example.

Here's a small demonstration:

```js
class Weather extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      weather: {"coord":{"lon":-95.37,"lat":29.76},"weather":[{"id":800,"main":"Clear","description":"clear sky","icon":"01n"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":285.56,"pressure":1022,"humidity":67,"temp_min":283.05,"temp_max":287.15},"visibility":16093,"wind":{"speed":2.27,"deg":115.002},"clouds":{"all":1},"dt":1542935700,"sys":{"type":1,"id":2646,"message":0.0041,"country":"US","sunrise":1542977570,"sunset":1543015369},"id":4699066,"name":"Houston","cod":200}
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.weather &&
          Object.keys(this.state.weather).map((weatherPropertyKey) => {
            return <div><b>{weatherPropertyKey}</b> = {JSON.stringify(this.state.weather[weatherPropertyKey])}</div>;
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Weather/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstand what a map function does. JavaScript objects basically are a map, i.e. key value pairs. Use `mapStateToProps` to map the object stored in the redux state to a prop the component uses, then just access it like any other object, i.e. `this.props.stateObject.fieldValue`